# Не отображаются изображения (Django)

Tags: python-3.x, django, bootstrap

Привет ребята, проблема заключается в следующем, используя Bootstrap 3, создал "Карусель" из изображений, далее во Views написал цикл, который добавляет все изображения с путями, в словарь, чтобы потом через цикл, вывести все изображения в HTML-views.

---

**HTML**

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
<!-- Indicators -->
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
</ol>
<!-- Wrapper for slides -->
<div class="carousel-inner">
    {% for picture in picture_list %}
    <div class="item active"><img src="{{ picture }}" style="width:100%;">
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
<!-- Left and right controls -->
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</a>
```

**Views**

```
def recipes_list(request):
recipes = Recipe.objects.filter(created_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('created_date')
pictures = os.listdir(os.path.join(settings.STATIC_PATH, 'images/carousel'))
picture_list = []
for picture in pictures:
    path = str(os.path.join(settings.STATIC_PATH, 'images\carousel').replace('\\', '/'))
    picture_list.append('%s/%s' % (path, picture))
return render(request, 'Recipes/recipes_list.html', {'recipes': recipes, 'sub_form': sub_form, 'picture_list': picture_list})
```

Через браузер просматриваю путь до изображений, вроде все верно:

```
<img src="C:/Users/%username%/PycharmProjects/Django/CookBook/Recipes/static/images/carousel/FRIED SAGE1.jpg" style="width:100%;">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Здесь находится решение моей проблемы, спасибо **Ashish Nitin Patil**.
[Решение проблемы](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48851220/images-are-not-displayed-on-web-page-django)

Answer (score 0):

через браузер вы вводите ссылку на диск C. Web сервер умеет показывать из папки /media/
Нужно использовать что-то вроде  /media/{{ picture }}